# How to set text into TextArea with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to set some Text into the TextArea which has some kind of text to it by default which when clicked clears out and then you can set text to it, but I'm enable to perform it with webdriver using java.

---

Here's the code snippet of the TextArea:

`<textarea id="gwt-uid-13" class="v-textarea v-widget v-textarea-required v-required v-has-width v-textarea-prompt" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-12" aria-required="true" rows="5" tabindex="0" style="width: 600px;" maxlength="4000"/>`

---

Here's what I have tried so far:
element is the TextArea control itself:

```
element= driver.findElement(By.id("gwt-uid-13"))
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("Modification Comment TextArea");
```

---

Also, I tried first clicking the element too:

`element.click(); element.clear(); element.sendKeys("Modification Comment TextArea");`

Please check out the images attached for more info:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have errors? because according to the image you posted it works

Comment: Did you try by removing `element.clear();` line?

Comment: I don't get the problem. The text you're training to send, is there. Are you worrying, that it's still grey? If so, that seems to be a problem within your GUI logic.

Comment: @guy - No, it did not gave me any errors, the image shows the value inserted, But when we perform some action on other elements or even if I click the same element the text gets removed.

Comment: @MosamMehta - when remove `element.clear();` line it goes to append the text to "Enter Common Comment" text which was present by default.

Comment: @PeterWippermann - The Default Text "Enter Common Comment " seems to be some kind of logic that is when the textArea is empty it should appear that message and it vanishes when you perform click action on it, 
manually when you click and type in it works perfect the text gets entered. But with Automation when I perform `element.sendKeys("Some Comment");` it goes to modify that default text value, which vanishes when I click on the textArea again that means the text was not set.

Comment: the default text value is similar to a [placeholder](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.placeholder). So when you use Automation to sendKeys it updates the placeholder Value not the actual text inside TextArea. 
please find definition  at this link - [placeholder](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/textarea.html#textarea.attrs.placeholder)

Comment: @AmeetV27 As I said, the problem is likely in the implementation of your functionality "similar to a placeholder". First, you should ask yourself, if you really need this proprietary functionality. Why not use the native placeholder? If that's no option for you, you should share more of exactly that "similar to placeholder" code. My guess would be that this is not cleanly implemented.

Comment: @PeterWippermann - I guess you are right. I will have to look into it further with our Dev Team. Mean while a work around that worked for me:
perform `element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);` on the same element before performing `element.clear()` and then `element.sendKeys("Modification comment TextArea")` - I don't know the exact reason why this is working but I think I can go ahead with this. 
Thanks & Cheers everyone who helped.

Answer (score 4):

This is something that works for me (got to know this with trial and error) -
instead of performing click() first, I tried sending TAB and clear and the value.

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("Some Sample Text Here");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the text is very long, SendKeys can time out, take a long time or be instable. What might work then is copy the text to the clipboard and then send `OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v"` to the text area element.
A drawback of this method is that you will need awt or Swing in Java, or System.Windows or System.Windows.Forms in C#.

Answer (score 0):

I make use of the javascript executor.

org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor.executeScript(String, Object...)

And instead do:

```
   String javascriptToExecute = String.format("document.getElementById('%1$s').value = decodeURI('%2$s');  ",
                componentId, uriEcondedValue);

getJavascriptExecutor().executeScript(javascriptToExecute);
```