# geckobrowser set a value in a textarea using c#

Tags: gecko

Hi i wan set a test of a text area using gecko browser 
that is the html of my page

```
<textarea id="noteField" data-nemo="note-field" class="textArea_gebdo3" style="height: 44px;">texthere</textarea>
```

as you can see the vaule is not setted in value="text" so i can use usually code for get element and set the vale some idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

This post have a solution in Java with SendKey():

[How to set text into TextArea with Selenium Webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126293/how-to-set-text-into-textarea-with-selenium-webdriver)

It seems to be close to your problem but it's not the best solution.

Comment: but im not using java and selenium dont work with my browser